# Pendulum in radial gravity field

Tags: classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, oscillators

All I could find about pendulums assumes that the force on the pendulum mass $m$ is $mg$ directed downwards. The case of $m$ being attracted only by the radial gravity pull (thus replacing the "plane" gravity field of earth) of a greater mass $M$ situated not too far below $m$ seems not to have been treated. Maybe because the equations are quite straight forward but yield a time period $T$ equal to a constant times $\int dx \; (\sin x)^4/\sqrt{1-(a-b(\sin x)^4)^2}$, where x is an integration parameter. This integral, which involves elliptical functions, does not appear in any of my searches so I would like to know if anybody has come across this problem or could point me in the right direction.

Comment: The usual treatment of a pendulum is an approximation because it assumes the motion of the bob is one dimensional. Removing this approximation makes the pendulum an anharmonic oscillator with no analytic solution for the equatin of motion. Retaining the approximation but bring the mass near produces similar anharmonic motion with no analytic solution. You can either use perturbation theory or Fourier expand the motion.

Comment: Maybe I forgot to state that I assume the bob swings in the yz plane. The mass M is at (0,0,0), the pivot at (0,0,L) and the pendulum arm (massless) has length A. If the bob is at (0,y,z) then its distance from (0,0,0) is R, which has a maximum value of B. Then the potential energy decrease as the bob swings from B to R is gmM(1/R-1/B)=mv^2/2 where v is the tangential velocity. Some further calculations together with putting R=B(sinx)^2 leads to the integral mentioned.  T is inversly proportional to sqrt(gM). If the system moves uniformly in the x direction only M and g can be effected by SR..

Comment: Because all length are perpendicular to the direction of motion. Now T = gamma T0 and M = gamma M0 so to make things tally one must conclude that g = gamma g0, where the 0 signifies stationary values. Finding out how uniform motion affects g was my original motive for investigating this pendulum.

Comment: Your last statement confuses me, how is there a correlation between $g$ and some other uniform motion? $g$ is fixed as $\frac{GM_e}{R_e^2}$ where $M_e$ and $R_e$ are the mass and radius of Earth at the equator.